# Is there a performance hit by loading javascript dynamically from the client

Tags: javascript, css

Take two scripts.  One uses  tag to load javascript:

```
<script src="/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and  tag for css:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
```

another method is to dynamically load it via javascript like:

```
fileRef = document.createElement('script');
fileRef.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
fileRef.setAttribute('src', url);
```

or for css dynamic loading:

```
fileRef = document.createElement('link');
fileRef.setAttribute('rel',  'stylesheet');
fileRef.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
fileRef.setAttribute('href', url);
```

Ive seen other libraries (just cant think of the name) that loads your scripts dynamically.  Aside from making sure that you dont load scripts that already has been loaded is there a performance hit for loading it dynamically from the client instead of just hard coding each file using  and/or  on the page (statically or in server side)?

Comment: It's similar to loading them at the end of your document (above the `</body>` that is) in terms of performance.

Comment: No, there isn't a performance hit, but you might end up running into security restrictions when injecting scripts.

Comment: RequireJS and similar AMD libraries (dojo...) are good for performance, but since you are loading the entire library, performance should be the same both ways.

Comment: The scripts and all within my domain only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a difference and it has to do with the roundtrip time from server to client and back. Two statically defined scripts will load in parallel but if you have one file1.js that is dynamically loading a second file file2.js, file2 will be delayed 2*pingtime to your server. Also the web client will put the second request last in the request queue which means that if you have many images, stylesheets etc you might delay the initial startup time considerably.

Comment: NP. If performance is your goal, look into Grunt and to minify all your resources into one file. Quite a lot of performance can be gained by limiting the amount of requests to your server. Especially on mobile.